# Looking for advice, domain controller/remote logon

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-7, domain-controller

Alright, so we currently have 2 locations with 10 pcs at each location. We're looking for a solution that will allow us to have any user, use any PC, at either location and be able to login without having 20 profiles on every PC.

I'm assuming it's not something easily doable without getting into active directory/domain controller but I'm getting hung-up on the DNS aspect of it. We have a valid domain with a DNS server for the website and as silly as it sounds, I assumed it would be as easy as adding a record pointing to the Windows server and then setting up the workstations to authenticate against that record which obviously points to that Windows server IP...

So realistically the question is a.) what solution is best to allow any user to login to any pc (preferably with previous sessions saved state) and b.) how to handle the DNS aspect since the server itself doesn't need ANY sort of DNS functionality as all of the workstations and servers can just use the ISP dns resolvers? It really just seems like potential overkill to get all crazy with what would seemingly be something fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

Set up Active Directory. It really sounds to me like you want Active Directory. AD is the single-sign on tool you want that allows users to log on to any domain-joined machine and service with their same set of credentials, with roaming profiles, and centralized group policies, and so forth and so on.

Name your domain as a subdomain of your public domain.  For example, if your website or "public presence" is foo.com, name your AD domain something like internal.foo.com.

Add your ISP DNS as your DNS servers' forwarders.

All internal clients will use your AD DC as their DNS server.

Don't be afraid to hire a consultant to help you.

Comment: How do you deal with the profiles?

Comment: You'll still have one profile on a Windows machine for each person who interactively logs on to that machine. There is no getting around that, with or without Active Directory. Unless you intend to share a singe account among many people, which I strongly discourage. At least with AD roaming profiles (which can be a pain in the ass themselves sometimes,) your user's profiles can at least travel with them from PC to PC.

Comment: Hey Ryan, I finally got it working locally in terms of I'm able to get a Workstation to actually try authenticating to the server and I've setup two users on the server but when I try logging on to either user on the Workstation is keeps saying "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed".

When I created the user accounts I didn't setup profile paths and home folder is set to local path but I don't THINK that has anything to do since it seems like it's not even getting to the point of logging on...